# How to use CDbCriteria in Yii to apply SQL filters on Model

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I try to get this mysql query to work with Yii model but i can't.

```
SELECT COUNT( qhc.countries_id) AS counter, q.question, co.name 
FROM questions AS q , countries as co, questions_has_countries AS qhc
WHERE qhc.questions_id = q.id 
AND co.id = qhc.countries_id
GROUP BY question
HAVING counter = 2
```

So far i have this, but somehow thou it seems ok, it doesnt work :

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(); 
$criteria->select = 'question, COUNT(countries_id) as counter';
$criteria->with = array('countries', 'categories');
$criteria->addInCondition('countries.id' , $_POST['Questions']['countries']);
$criteria->group = 'question';
$criteria->having = ('counter = 1');
$model = Questions::model()->findAll($criteria)
```

Pls help, I'am pretty new to Yii framework.

Thanks.

Sql from the log :

```
SELECT `t`.`question` AS `t0_c1`,
COUNT(countries_id) as counter, `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `countries`.`id` AS
`t1_c0`, `countries`.`name` AS `t1_c1`, `categories`.`id` AS `t2_c0`,
`categories`.`name` AS `t2_c1` FROM `questions` `t`  LEFT OUTER JOIN
`questions_has_countries` `countries_countries` ON
(`t`.`id`=`countries_countries`.`questions_id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `countries`
`countries` ON (`countries`.`id`=`countries_countries`.`countries_id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `questions_has_categories` `categories_categories` ON
(`t`.`id`=`categories_categories`.`questions_id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN
`categories` `categories` ON
(`categories`.`id`=`categories_categories`.`categories_id`)  WHERE
(countries.id=:ycp0) GROUP BY question HAVING (counter = 2). Bound with
:ycp0='1'
```

Comment: Why do you need Yii's `$criteria` when you can achieve absolutely the same thing via pure SQL?

Comment: Since you're new to Yii, remember that Yii is one of 3-world's worst frameworks ever. Instead learn Zend2 or Symfony2

Comment: That's least valuable comment to the issue u guys did. Congrats.

Answer (score 1):

You have done most of work. Now you need to call the `$criteria` into model. Just like this

```
$rows = MODEL ::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Where `MODEL` is model class of table which you want to apply criteria on.

To learn more about this you can follow this [CActiveRecord Class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CActiveRecord%E2%80%8E).

Comment: LOL, ofc I had written MODEL ::model()->findAll($criteria); it still doesnt work. Doesnt select the right entities

Comment: No, I get no results for counter = 1 ( there should be some) , and i get the right results for counter = 2. No errors, just it fetches something else then it should :(

Comment: please be sure ,that counter = 1 , does actually have any result in database :)

Comment: It works when i apply above query in raw mysql at php-my-admin for both counter = 1 , counter = 2 and so on. It doesnt work when i try it Yii way.

Comment: dont't put any () in having , try this

Comment: i did try. That's also not an issue :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `together` in `CDbCriteria`

```
...
$criteria->together = true;
$model = Question::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use "as counter", your model must have a property named "counter" or it will not load it into your model.

if you don't have a property named "counter", try using another one of your models property that you are not selecting right now : "as someColumn"

and use condition or addCondition or .. instead of having

cheers